# WinForm: Inherited Panel wont Autosize

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

first of all: my English is pretty bad. I'm sorry if there are some grammar and writing errors.

My question:

Our company is using the same DLL for a lot of programs. In on of those multiused DLLs, we created some basic UI object, that are used very often. But we found a bug, when the DLL is used in a specific programm:

My team created a panel via WinForm. Normaly it works great: Whenever you start a panel, the form is autosized according to the current free space it got. To realize this, we used following code:

```
this.tableLayoutPanelMain.AutoSize = true;
            this.tableLayoutPanelMain.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

No problems so far. But, after this specific panel is used again in the SAME program - I think this created panel is inherited somehow -  it wont autosize anymore. Instead it got the pre-defined size:

```
this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(341, 69);
```

I dont have any idea, why the panel isnt reloading again and autosizing again. The biggest issue here is, that I dont have access to the specific program, where this bug occurs and our DLL is used. I just know that this error somehow occours there.

I am not a pro-programmer. But I think that it has something to do how they implemented the panel. I think, that they created it once, but never again. So there is just one panel, used pretty often. But while doing this, it wont refresh, nor using the autosize function aymore.

To prevent this bug, I believe I somehow have to implement something like: constantly refresh, whenever used, please autosize.

But I have absolutley no idea. I've never worked with winforms, just with XAML. So if anyone could help me with this, i would really appreciate it.

The code:

```
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.AutoSize = true;
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.ColumnCount = 3;
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 16F));
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 218F));
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(this.panelPasswordRepetitionError, 1, 2);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(this.txtRepetition, 2, 2);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(this.lblPasswordRepetition, 0, 2);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(this.panelPasswordError, 1, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(this.txtPassword, 2, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(this.panelDummy, 0, 1);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(this.passwordQualityBox1, 2, 1);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Name = "tableLayoutPanelMain";
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.RowCount = 3;
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(341, 69);
    this.tableLayoutPanelMain.TabIndex = 0;
```

Forgot this:

```
// PDFPasswordView
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.AutoSize = true;
this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange;
this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanelMain);
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.Name = "PDFPasswordView";
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(341, 69);
this.Validated += new System.EventHandler(this.OnPDFPasswordViewValidated);
this.tableLayoutPanelMain.ResumeLayout(false);
this.tableLayoutPanelMain.PerformLayout();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.errorProvider)).EndInit();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.markerProvider)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
```

Comment: I would guess it fits parent because of this line: `this.tableLayoutPanelMain.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill` Anyway, if it works properly in different programs, it would be better to fix it in the program that has the error, rather than in the library that is most likely working properly

Comment: I wish I could, but this company is very decentralized. There is no way they would grant me any access to that programs sourcecode. It's simply not my business to play with their source code. I have to accept that.

So we have to fix it somehow by ourselves. And as it is my task to fix it, I have to do it..and I got absolutley no Idea how to do it.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why you are responsible for fixing code you cannot even see, but I'm afraid we cannot help you for the same reason. The part you showed us looks fine and information you offer is not enough to figure out the cause of this issue. I wish you best luck with this task.

Comment: It does not make much sense. If the base control has desired properties values but a derived control does not works as expected, then it is because the derived control override base panel property. Obviously, the error must be fixed where the problem is. If you try to fix it in the base control by some hacking, then you might break something else elsewhere where a different behaviour is desired. If the problem is in the other company code, then it is up to them to fix it. By the way, you should not fix a problem that you don't understand as you might break even more things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I just found out what the problem was:

It is working if started via Debug Mode (Attach to process), but not when started as release. This really seems to be weird. Seems like the release is jumping over some code.

Comment: It does not make much sense. Either, there is bad code (like improper use of `Debug.Assert`) or the application is not properly build in some cases. So you might try **Rebuild all**

Comment: I tried to rebuild the project allready and it still didnt work. There is no use of Debug.Assert, too.

I am absolutley clueless...the only way it worked was when i manually setted up the size, but I dont want to do that, as the form wont be flexible anymore.