# Program only works correctly in debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, debugging, dll

Here is my previous question, if you want some further information regarding my current problem:

[WinForm: Inherited Panel wont Autosize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203042/winform-inherited-panel-wont-autosize/39226307?noredirect=1#comment65798320_39226307)

If you don't want to read through it, I'll give you some general information:

- I'm not working directly via the programme, I'm just editing a specific DLL, that is used by this programme
- That means, that I don't have any access to the source code of this specific programme
- That also means that I have to fix this problem via some changes in the DLL, that is - as I mentioned before - used by this programme.

What I found out so far:

- It works without any problems, if I attach the programme to the DLL's source code in VS2015.
- But it has some glitches if I build the code and then copy the DLL into the programme's folder - that's also my actual problem: it somehow shrinks the tableLayoutpanel to half its actual size and I get some weird glitches in the other half of its actual, in normal start somehow not used, size.

What I tried out:

- I changed the size manually, not via `"Dock = Fill" or "Autosize = true"` and it worked. But that's, as you all may know, not the best solution and we only want to use it, if there is absolutely no other way around it. No one likes to hard-code.
- I tried to inherit its Parent's Size via:

  `this.tablelayoutPanel.Size = this.Size;`
  and
  `this.tableLayoutPanel.Size = new Size(this.Height, this.Size);`

So do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: How about debugging the release mode version?

Comment: That happens to me once. It turns out that, the environment variables of the two process are different. You can use process explorer to find it out.

Comment: @UweKeim Yeah, that sounds like an good idea. I'll try that out soon.

Comment: @neohope You mean the process explorer in the task manager?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

Comment: You obviously have access to the problem program's executable to be able to attach a debugger to it.  Why not use a disassembler to view how it uses/misuses your control.

Comment: @neohope I just tried it out. They are the same. Seems like that was not the problem.

Comment: @UweKeim Did not work, still the same problem.

Comment: @TnTinMn I never worked with a disassembler. I just tried it out in VS15, but I dont understand what any of these shown codes really mean. But as it works in debug mode, I dont think there will be any misuse of my control.

Comment: @TheOnionMaster, how do you really debug your app with the edited dll file? If you want to debug a library file with one programme, why did you use the "attach to process"? You can use the start external program. If it works well in debug mode, do you find any differences in the two mode in your project file(.xxxproj file)? Do you get any exception/warning messages in release mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did not figured out why the debuger worked and the release/debug build not. But I just forced a redraw on the tableLayoutPanelMainwith with `Application.DoEvents()`. I never tried this out before, because `Invalidate()` + `Update()` or `Refresh()` did not work - I was like: okay, that wont be that easy, so just forget about that.

But after some trial & error and a lot of time...well, I was working for two weeks on it...I tried the simpliest thing out and YEAHY, it worked!

Anyways, thank you for your help, guys. I appreciate that.

Comment: If you're solving a problem with DoEvents then likely you are papering over the real problem rather than fixing it. Fixing problems with DoEvents is dangerous; it can introduce unexpected re-entrancy. And it is symptomatic of fixing problems at random rather than understanding the problem and applying a principled, correct fix at the architectural level.

Comment: So you've got any idea to fix it correctly? Why is Refresh() not working? I really believe that the team that used our DLL has done the problem. My solution is more like a workaround. I'm aware of that, but as long as I'm not allowed to change the external sourcecode, it's my only way to fix it. I'm not really "happy" with this solution either, as I really believe this can damage other programs that use the same DLL, too. But:

It's in test preperation anyways, so as long as it works: It's okay. And if not: I'll try to find another solution.